# Screencasting/Mirroring from a USB connected iOS device

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

For AppleTV, the **proprietary** AirPlay protocol is used for Screen Mirroring, this incorporate encoding the video on the device and sending the compressed data over the network to the Mirror destination.

Having a USB connected iPhone device, is it possible to mirror the screen in the same manner? is there API for this kind of functionality? can this be done for an iPhone device connected to a windows OS?

Comment: You can use iTools for USB screen mirror (the windows version). But I don't know how it works or how could you do it yourself.

Comment: Cool, this actually works, Have to figure out what is the underling mechanism used...

Comment: iTools is using the same interface iTunes is using to manage the device, un-fortunately, this support screen capture at a reate of no more than few frames per second, To get a real mirroring session you can use CoreMediaIO in the same manner used on Yosemite to mirror a device connected using a lightning cable

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Mirroring functionality introduced with iOS8 and Yosemite, see [this blog](https://nadavrub.wordpress.com/2015/07/06/macos-media-capture-using-coremediaio/) for details

Answer (score 0):

This is possible now on Windows, I show a screenshot here for your reference. Software will be available in the future.

https://plus.google.com/u/1/114395554184391775867/posts/N3pKpzK8A6K